# How to prepare column names dynamically in a sql query in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

A table in SQLite DB contains 52 columns and their name as follows
**size0,size1,size2,size3,....size49,category,priority**.

while preparing the query for getting the values in only sizes columns i'm writing the query as

**select size0,size1,size2,size3,....size49 from myTableName**.

Can we prepare these column names **dynamically in a loop**( **because all size columns are in logical order** ) **within the query it self**?

and that **query should work in sqlite**.

Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This MUST be a horrible db design. Normalize it!!!

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite, you can't change columns number or column definition in a query with plain SQL.

Anyways, this MUST be a horrible database design. Consider normalizing your schema, as I can't believe 200 `size` columns is a correct solution to any real problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
SELECT * FROM mytablename
```

The * will return all data (columns) from the table.

Comment: ah, then you have a problem. @LS_DEV comment about redesign is a good one. the only other option i can think of, is to use the procedural language (php, javascript or whatever your app uses) to parse the resultset array